# Is there a JSON or YAML specification available for AWS SAM, similar to CloudFormation?

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-sam

I maintain [VaporShell](https://github.com/SCRT-HQ/VaporShell), a PowerShell module to abstract CloudFormation template creation. As part of the CI pipeline, it pulls down the current [CloudFormation specification JSON](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-resource-specification.html) to generate the functions for resource types and resource property types.

**Is there a similar specification JSON (or YAML) for SAM?**

I currently manually maintain the SAM specific code, but I'd like to ensure that any new resources / properties / etc are pulled in as the SAM team releases them. If I have a JSON or YAML specification available, that would make my life much easier as well as ensure up-to-date SAM support within VaporShell.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately for the [`AWS::Serverless` types](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-specification-resources-and-properties.html), there is no officially maintained specification:

https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/issues/1133

but there seems to be an unofficial specification many projects share so the maintenance can be shared across projects at least:

https://github.com/awslabs/goformation/blob/master/generate/sam-2016-10-31.json

Comment: You are a saint!!! Thank you so much, this should work perfectly!!!